# DRF Create queryset by adding foreign key queryset into it

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to get **foreign data(Child model)** into **Parent Model queryset**.

I am able to add **foreign data** into **Parent data** but it is **JSON**. I want to convert that **JSON** into queryset because **get_queryset()** returns **model/queryset**.

I googled a lot but unable to find anything helpful.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.TextField()
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, related_name="+", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


class Child(models.Model):
    child_name = models.TextField()


class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParentInfoSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ['parent_name']

   def get_queryset(self):
        response = []
        parent_name = self.request.GET.getlist("parent_name")[0]# 
        parent_queryset = 
              Parent.objects.filter(parent_name=parent_name)
        for par_queryset in parent_queryset:
            parent_result = self.serializer_class(phy_queryset).data
            child_id = physician_info_result["child"]
            child_instance = Child.objects.get(pk=child_id)
            child_result = ChildSerializer(child_instance).data
            parent_result["child"] = child_result
            response.append(parent_result)
       return response
```

**URL -**

```
http://localhost:9000/api/parent?parent_name=xyz
```

**Response output** is:

**[{
    "parent_name": "xyz",
    "child": [{
        "id": 1
        "child_name": "abc"
    }]
}]**

But above output it is **JSON** which I **don't** want. I want output into **queryset/model**.

***NOTE***: Queryset output should contain foreign queryset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just replace the default field for child to child serializer and it'll work like you want.

```
class ParentSerializer(models.Model):
    child = ChildSerializer()

     class Meta:
         models = Parent
         fields = ('parent_name', 'child')
```

And you also don't need to override the `get_queryset` method.

Comment: I do agree with @Ivan Semochkin.